# bootstrap links to subpage not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, menu

So, I downloaded some bootstrap free theme and try to modify it the way I want to.
https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524939-heera-responsive-html5-multipurpose-template

When clicking on links to subpages (About us, Procedures & Prices, Contact & Location) nothing happens. What is stopping them from opening? 
I'm a beginner, any advice is greatly appreciated!

```css
.main-menu {
  background-color: #5D4E61;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0px;
}
.menu-logo {
  display: none;
  max-width: 125%;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #dddada;
}
.menu-list {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.menu-list .active a {
  color: #dddada;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="menu-logo">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="menu Logo">
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.menu-logo -->
      </div>
      <nav id="menu" class="menu collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="headernavigation" class="menu-list nav navbar-nav wow fadeInUp animated">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Procedures & Prices</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Contact & Location</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.menu-list -->
      </nav>
      <!-- /.menu-list -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</header>
<!-- /#main-menu -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take an example:

```
<li><a href="index.html">Procedures & Prices</a></li>
```

Notice that the a-tag is pointing to `index.html`. If your webpage, is called `index.html`, all it'll do it loop back to itself. You'll want to put another webpage as the destination for the a-tag.

Read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: That's true, I've put them there because I don't have the subpages ready yet. Except 'about.html', this subpage's finished and it's still not working. Even when clicking on a-tag 'index.html' page's not refreshing.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have within the same directory, two files, index.html and about.html? And when you click on "About us" (from the index.html file) it doesn't go anywhere? (Because... it should in that case.)

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` is your homepage right?

All your links are pointing to the home page `<a href="index.html">`

Change the `index.html` to whatever the other pages are called, for example if you create a page called `about.html` the anchor tag would look like `<a href="about.html">`

Comment: But one of the a-tags is about.html and it's still not working